# Proper usage of lateral join

Tags: postgresql

There are 2 tables:

```sql
create table strikes
(
    id                                bigint generated always as identity
        constraint pk_strikes
            primary key,
    planned_on_date                   date,
    goals                             text    not null,
    results                           text,
    overall_num_of_employees_involved integer not null
        constraint ck_strikes_overall_num_of_employees_involved_positive
            check (overall_num_of_employees_involved >= 1),
    updated_at                        timestamp with time zone,
    duration                          tstzrange,
    enterprise_id                     bigint  not null
        constraint fk_strikes_enterprise_id_enterprises
            references enterprises,
    created_by_id                     bigint  not null
        constraint fk_strikes_created_by_id_users
            references users,
    union_in_charge_id                bigint
        constraint fk_strikes_union_in_charge_id_unions
            references unions
            on delete set null
);
create table strike_to_user_associations
(
    strike_id bigint not null
        constraint fk_strike_to_user_associations_strike_id_strikes
            references strikes
            on delete cascade,
    user_id   bigint not null
        constraint fk_strike_to_user_associations_user_id_users
            references users
            on delete cascade,
    role      userrole,
    constraint pk_strike_to_user_associations
        primary key (strike_id, user_id)
);
```

Second table `strike_to_user_associations` is a m2m intermediate table represents connections between `user` and `strike`.

I have made a following query:

```sql
select count(*), sub.aa, sub.ab
from strikes
join lateral (
    select
        array_agg(strike_to_user_associations.strike_id) as aa,
        array_agg(strike_to_user_associations.strike_id) filter ( where strikes.duration @> now()) as ab
    from strike_to_user_associations
    where strike_to_user_associations.user_id = strikes.created_by_id
    ) as sub on true
where created_by_id = 34
group by  sub.aa, sub.ab
;
```

that theoretically should return following:

1. Count of strikes from `strike` table which have been created by exact user (`created_by_id` field).
2. Array of `strike_id` from `strike_to_user_associations` table where `user_id` is the same as in `strike` table.
3. Array of `strike_id` from `strike_to_user_associations` table where `user_id` is the same as in `strike` table but with extra criteria `strikes.duration @> now()` i.e active now strikes.

What this query returns as it is:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|count|aa   |ab   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|1    |{176}|{176}|
|3    |{176}|null |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

What i want it to return:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|count|aa   |ab   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|4    |{176}|{176}|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

As it is query result is split into 2 rows:

- **first** count of active strikes , array of strike_id, array of active strike_id (with filter)
- **second** count of non - active strikes, array of strike_id, array of active strike_id (with filter)

Expected output - count of all strikes for exact user, array of strike_id, array of active strike_id (with filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't want to `GROUP BY sub.aa, sub.ab` but rather to `GROUP BY created_by_id` - or really, not group by anything at all.

Also I don't see a reason to use a lateral join here. This query would be more clear with simple subqueries:

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM strikes
    WHERE created_by_id = 34
  ) AS count_created,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT strike_id
    FROM strike_to_user_associations
    WHERE user_id = 34
  ) AS strikes_participated,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT strike_id
    FROM strike_to_user_associations
    JOIN strikes ON strike_to_user_associations.user_id = strikes.created_by_id
    WHERE strike_to_user_associations.user_id = 34
      AND strikes.duration @> now()
  ) AS "???";
```

And I suspect that you made a mistake in the join condition between `strike_to_user_associations` and `strikes`. Your current query (and my above subquery) are getting all strikes that are active and were created by user 34, and then are cross-joining that with all strikes to which user 34 has an association with. This weird condition is also the reason why your lateral subquery returned different `ab` results per strike before the aggregation. I guess what you actually want here is match `strike_to_user_associations.strike_id = strikes.id`, so as to get an array of the active strikes that the user is associated with.

Comment: Yes, this way it is much better. I just tried to make it happen with lateral as it seemed for me correct way to do so... Thanks